# How does c# handle nested (generic) types?

Tags: c#, types, nested

I'm trying to understand how C# views types in the face of nesting.
More specifically I'm trying to understand why some types are not considered assignment compatible or even castable, when there "kind of" only exist one definition of the nested class. Does the compiler / CLR actually generate different types for these, or what rules are at play exactly...

Example code:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    protected class Private2 : Private1<Foo<T>>
    { }

    protected class Private1<T2> where T2 : Foo<T>
    {
        public sealed class Nested
        {
            public void Test(T2 foo)
            {
                foo.Method2(this); //Nope!
                var nes = (Private2.Nested)this; //Nope!
            }
        }
    }

    public void Method1()
    {
        var nested = new Private2.Nested();
        nested.Test(this);
    }

    private void Method2(Private2.Nested nested)
    {
        // something code...
    }
}
```

So even though the nested instance is created as a Private2.Nested it can not be casted to that type. And... well... how do the different Nested types relate to each other given that Nested is in fact sealed? (They can't be inheriting from each other right? But on the other hand their implementation should be 100% identical... am I wrong?)

**Primary question:** What exactly is the compiler doing when it "compiles" this nested class?? How many unique types (excluding valuetype-related) are actually generated, and if it is all the "same" type, is the restriction artificial (as in wouldn't an unsafe cast actually work)? (What I'm saying is that the IL for all these types comes from the same code definition - so at some level the compiler must know. Are instances of these types not bit-for-bit identical apart from their type-names?)

---

**Secondary question:** not what I'm really asking here, mostly for brevity / context: is there some simple change that would make the above work? Am I missing something obvious?

The type `Foo<T>` must never be directly referenced inside `Private1<T2>` - only use of `T2` is allowed. `Foo<T>` is just my example stand in for nasty generic classes with 10~20 generic types. It's all just a "workaround" for not being able to alias a generic class with its types:

```
public class Bar<GoodName, OtherName, Readability, NopeMr, DontThinkSo, Suffering, Dispair>
{
    //If only this was real...
    using BarT = Bar<GoodName, OtherName, Readability, NopeMr, DontThinkSo, Suffering, Dispair>;

    public void Method1(BarT bar) { ... } //so good!!

    //goodbye readability... see you never...
    public void Method2(Bar<GoodName, OtherName, Readability, NopeMr, DontThinkSo, Suffering, Dispair> whatIsThisVariable) { ... }
}
```

Purpose: To avoid types of fields and method-parameters that are several screens wide and ***utterly*** unreadable! >:(

*...As a side note I really wished `this` could be used as a type inside classes and interfaces, as in `Private2 : Private1<this>`. Well ok, that wouldn't work because it collides with extension syntax on methods, but something similar, perhaps `<this>`, `<super>`, `<base>` used like `Method(<this> arg)` or `Private2 : Private1<<super>>` ... kind of weird maybe.*

Comment: Putting aside the question about what the compiler is generating, I think the reason it doesn't allow this is just another case the compiler not being smart enough to realise that due to your generic constraints that within `Test` it must be dealing with `Private2` by analysing all the other code within the surrounding class, `Foo<T>`.  [Semi related blog post](http://ericlippert.com/2013/07/15/why-are-generic-constraints-not-inherited/) from Eric Lippert

Comment: @JamesThorpe I guess that _could_ be related. But at some point it has to decide if this is the same type or not, if nothing else than to generate the code, so how many types would this one definition in fact yield? I guess what I'm asking is "Does the compiler simply 'copy' my code for each 'nesting', basically like a precompiler macro?" I mean if it did then that _implies_ that it recognizes that they are internally identical. o_0 I.e. they might not be related in the classical sense, but practically interchangeable - implied question: or is there a case where they are not?

Comment: Why would you want to make a private class sealed?

Comment: @TimothyShields it's supposed to be protected, I just didn't think about it when I typed the example code since it's not directly related to the question. Edit: changed.

Comment: I tried to figure out a solution to "I really wished this could be used". It's possible to declare `class Foo<T, ThisType> where ThisType : Foo<T, ThisType>` and reuse the generic param `class Private2 : Private1<ThisType>`, but good luck figuring out how to declare a `Foo<int, Foo<int, Foo<int,...`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6618134/84206 for more on this fun.

Comment: @AaronLS oh you should see the code-base I'm working on... xD That much is not to bad. And it's perfectly doable, it's basically the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). I am using it quite a bit, and it is partly because of that that I'm suffering with type-names several lines long... ;___;

Comment: @AaronLS Following your link --> the accepted answer --> link to Erics blog (side note: that post is actually where I first heard of CRTP) --> comment section --> in comment by Eugene --> I found [this interesting link](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aldrich/courses/819/f-bounded.pdf). Its a paper on "F-bounded polymorphism for OOP". It doesn't answer my questions but it _is_ an interesting read related the underlying problems my real code is trying to deal with.

Comment: Please don't write things like 'edit' in your question unnecessarily - there's an edit history field that people can use to see what changed if needed. I  general you should write the question as though you were curating it for publication in a collection, not as a continually evolving brain dump. You should also stick to the Q&A format here - I removed a chunk that looked like a solution in need of review rather than part of the question. You can add it back (but might like to post it as part of your answer and get feedbac) if you make it fit within the question itself better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this types:

```
public class Base {
    public static int Value;
    public class Nested { }
}
public class Derived:Base { }
```

What is `Derived.Value` and `Derived.Nested`. Actually, when you refer to inherited static members (nested class considered to be static member) thru derived class, you just reference base class members, so this have exactly same meaning as `Base.Value` and `Base.Nested` at compile time. There are no separate static field `Derived.Value` or separate class `Derived.Nested`.

```
public static void Test() {
    Derived.Value=10;
    Console.WriteLine(Base.Value);
    Base.Value=20;
    Console.WriteLine(Derived.Value);
    Base.Nested bn=new Derived.Nested();
    Derived.Nested dn=new Base.Nested();
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(Base.Nested).FullName);
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(Derived.Nested).FullName);
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(Base.Nested)==typeof(Derived.Nested));
}
```

**Original answer:**
`Foo<A>.Private1<B>.Nested` and `Foo<C>.Private1<D>.Nested` considered to be different types if `A`!=`C` or `B`!=`D`. They can share same implementation internally, but for assignment compatibility they are different. `Foo<T>.Private2.Nested` is just alias to `Foo<T>.Private1<Foo<T>>.Nested`. And even if `class Bar:Foo<A>{}`, classes `Foo<A>.Private1<Foo<A>>.Nested` and `Foo<A>.Private1<Bar>.Nested` still considered to be different types. So `Foo<T>.Private1<T2>.Nested` can not be converted to `Foo<T>.Private1<Foo<T>>.Nested` as `T2` is not necessary  `Foo<T>`.

Comment: I guess it's more of a covariance issue with generic types?

Comment: In current version of C# variance only applied to delegates and interfaces, not to classes.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about the lack of variance you mention, but expressed the above comment poorly. "I guess it's more of a covariance support issue with concrete generic types." would have been a more correct sentence.

Comment: Btw. If you have any more specific information regarding that internal part about sharing implementation that you could add to the answer then I will accept it. Because that is the part I'm most curious about. As it is you present the lay of the land, but I'm looking for the deep and gory details, the underlying cause for the things you have stated so to speak. (Ex: They _can_ share implementation? Why? How? What decides if they do? When do they / when do they not? What are the rules at play? Are there any rules for this?)

Comment: @AnorZaken "share implementation" what I meant is pure CLR optimization thing. Two types `C<A>` and `C<B>` where `A`!=`B` considered to be different even if type parameter does not affect `C<T>` type at all.

Comment: well the optimization seems quite agressive, seeing as runtime-casts are succeeding, as described in my answer. I think I might explore this further at some later time, but is it all just implementation details ("happens to work") or are there some rules at play ("will always work")?

Comment: @AnorZaken What cast do you referencing? From `Private3.Nested` to `Private2.Nested`? It is the same type at the **compile** time. Why cast should be failed when you cast object to it own type?

Comment: Ah, you are correct - that much is done at compile time. (I have removed the incorrect information).

Answer (score 1):

You're not thinking with portals. Your inner classes are already generalized on T.

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    private class Private2 : Private1
    { }

    private class Private1
    {
        public sealed class Nested
        {
            public void Test( Foo<T> foo )
            {
                foo.Method2( this ); //Yup
                var nes = (Private2.Nested)this; //Yup
            }
        }
    }

    public void Method1()
    {
        var nested = new Private2.Nested();
        nested.Test( this );
    }

    private void Method2( Private2.Nested nested )
    {
        // something code...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I will share the real reason behind this... there is not one `T`, there are in the range 10~20 :( I was trying to save TONS and TONS of typing out them all over and over again... with that design `Foo<T>`, including all its generics is neatly packaged into `T2` for internal use. Generics with more than ~5 types is utterly unreadable :/

Comment: Awarded you a point anyway since I failed to specify enough details in my original question, my bad.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just spent the last half hour thinking about your problem, and I don't think there is a good answer. Method2 takes a Private2.Nested; Private1.Nested could never be passed as that, because Private1.Nested and Private2.Nested are separate types.

Comment: Well thanks for your effort anyway :) (At this point I'm kind of curious if there is some "hack" that will do the trick - that's part of why I'm asking if they use identical IL-code - they should be bit-for-bit compatible apart for their type-names, no?)

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer to the primary question:**

*It was bugging me that you can make the code compile by changing Method2 to accept an object and cast it at runtime, because the nested instance is of the correct type (it's instantiated inside Method1). That would seem to work - as long as Foo is sealed - but as soon as someone else can subclass Private1 it is no longer guaranteed to work. (And thus not a solution.)  However testing this approach reveals:*

> > `Private2.Nested` is only a construct of syntax rules - using    `GetType()` on the resulting variable says `Private1.Nested` and    there is no `Private2.Nested` type.

*I think the irksome feeling I was getting from this (and why I concidered sealed to be related) was some kind of confusion on my part when it came to distinguishing between subtype and inheritance. Because the outer classes are inheriting (Private1 and Private2) it feels like inheritance, and thus it feels like it should somehow be castable. But if I understand this correctly they are merely of the same subtype:*

> > There need not be and is in fact no inheritance relation one way or the other (as the sealed clearly hints) because ["the inheritance hierarchy is distinct from from the subtype hierarchy"](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aldrich/courses/819/f-bounded.pdf), and thus a downright conversion would be needed (since casts are bound to the inheritance hierarchy).