# c# generic self-referencing declarations

Tags: c#, self-reference

I've been reading Albaharis' "C# 5.0 in A Nutshell" and I've encountered this in Generics section and it is said to be legal:

```
class Bar<T> where T : Bar<T> { ... }
```

And it meant nothing to me, although I've read the whole chapter carefully. I couldn't understand even a bit of it.

Can someone please explain it with some understandable naming, like:

```
class Person<T> where T : Person<T> { ... }
```

And a real-world application scenario where this usage is appropriate and useful?

Comment: maybe a bit helpful although it is NOT a duplicate or a solution to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618134/generic-class-with-self-referencing-type-constraint there is an example in the question with animals and ducks

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, this is called the " Curiously recurring template pattern"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It means that `T` must inherit from `Person<T>`.

This is a typical way to create type-specific methods or properties or parameters in the base class, specific to the actual descendant.

For instance:

```
public abstract class Base<T> where T : Base<T>, new()
{
    public static T Create()
    {
        var instance = new T();
        instance.Configure(42);
        return instance;
    }

    protected abstract void Configure(int value);
}

public class Actual : Base<Actual>
{
    protected override void Configure(int value) { ... }
}

...

 Actual a = Actual.Create(); // Create is defined in Base, but returns Actual
```

Answer (score 4):

It is helpful, when you work with some external library or framework(which you can't or don't want modify). For example, you have class `User` from this library and definitely developer, who will use it, will define `CustomUser` class, which is inherited from it (just for adding some custom fields). Also let's imagine, that `User` class has some references to another users, for example: creator and deletor (which obviously will be instances of `CustomUser` type). And at this case generic **self-referencing declaration** can help very well. We will pass type of descendant(`CustomUser`) as parameter to base(`User`) class, so at `User` class declaration we can set types of creator and deletor **exactly** as they will be at future(`CustomUser`), so **no casting** will be needed:

```
public class User<TCustomUser> where TCustomUser : User<TCustomUser>
{
    public TCustomUser creator {get;set;}
    public TCustomUser deletor {get;set;}

    //not convenient variant, without generic approach
    //public User creator {get;set;}
    //public User deletor {get;set;}     
}

public class CustomUser : User<CustomUser>
{
    //custom fields:
    public string City {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

**Usage:**

```
CustomUser customUser = getUserFromSomeWhere();
//we can do this
var creatorsAge = customUser.creator.Age;
//without generic approach:
//var creatorsAge = ((CustomUser)customUser.creator).Age;
```

Answer (score 2):

I might be a little late to the party but I want to share an unreal-world application scenario for fun :)

```cs
// self referencing list in c#
// we cant use generic type syntax: new List<List<List..
// but dynamic keyword comes to save us

var list = new List<dynamic>();
list.Add(list); // the "FBI! open up" part
Console.WriteLine(list[0][0][0][0][0][0][0].Count); // 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It is also helpful when you have a series of classes to write and you realize that 80% (pick a number) of the code is essentially the same except it varies by TYPE.

Writing a generic allows you to capture all that repetitive code in a base class and reuse it.

The specific pattern above is important/necessary because you want the **T** to be the class you are trying to write.

Imagine a framework where the crud object is based on crudBase and everything inherits from that.
Imagine further that you have a base class that helps you query those objects (queryBase) and there will be a 1:1 with crudBase and queryBase classes.

Making queryBase a generic is simple because its fairly obvious how you would  declare it

```
public abstract class queryBase<T> where T : crudBase
{
 public list<T> FindMatches(string SearchCriteria){}

  }
```

Without a generic, this would have to be in each concrete class because the return type changes. Generics are awesome.

what is a little less obvious is how to accomplish that same level of GENERIC nirvana with crudBase.
Assume you have 70% of the boiler plate CRUD code already in a subclass, but there is another 10% where the logic needs to reference the type.
(pick a number, the % numbers are not important)

The GENERIC solution is less obvious here. In the first case you GENERIC class is referencing a different class with **T**. In this case, you want to reference the same class with **T**.

using the pattern described above you can in fact achieve this :

```
public class crudBaseGeneric<T> where T : crudBaseGeneric<T>
{
     public <T> CopyMe(){}
  }
```

Here you will redefine your base class as a generic and you will be able to capture that last 10%.

Again, without generics, I have to copy paste my CopyMe() function in each concrete class.