# Force method parameter type to match object type

Tags: c#, types

Consider the following:

```
public interface IFoo
{
   IFoo Bar(IFoo other);
}
```

This doesn't quite mean what I want; it says that if a class implements `IFoo`, then it has a `Bar()` method that accepts *any* object who's type also implements `IFoo`. What I *want* to express is that `Bar()` accepts any object of *the same type* as the object it's called on. (I'd also like to guarantee that it returns that same type as well.)

What I *really* want to say is something like

```
this Bar(this other); // Obviously, this is a syntax error.

T Bar<T>(T other) where T : this; // Also not allowed.

T Bar<T>(T other) where T : typeof(this); // Nope.
```

Does anybody know how to do this? I can't figure it out.

(Obviously I could just check the type of the argument at run-time and throw an exception if it doesn't match. But I'd really rather have this guaranteed at compile-time...)

Comment: C# doesn't support this. The best you can do is to make `IFoo` generic and constrain the generic parameter to be IFoo`. Look at how `IComparable<T>` is declared. You'd almost always make `T` the same class as the implementing class, but the compiler does not force you to do so.

Comment: @Sweeper If that really is the answer, can you post it as an answer?

Comment: I didn't answer because I felt like this is a duplicate, hoping that someone else can find the dupe target...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic class with self-referencing type constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618134/generic-class-with-self-referencing-type-constraint)

Comment: @Sweeper I was surprised I couldn't find this question already... Maybe there is a dup somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, the closest I can come up with is this:

```
public interface IFoo<T>
{
    T Bar(T other);
}

public class Moo : IFoo<Moo> {...}

public void UseIFoo(T stuff) where T : IFoo<T> {...}
```

I had expected the `where T : IFoo<T>` to complain about the recusion in the type constraint... but it appears not to. It *seems* to compile just fine... I guess this is as close as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

```
    interface IFoo
    {
        T Bar<T>(T foo) where T : IFoo;
    }
```

Well, no underlines in IDE. Should be allowed. Return and argument should be the same type. Example usage:

```
    interface IFoo
    {
        T Bar<T>(T foo) where T : IFoo;
    }

    class Foo : IFoo
    {
        public T Bar<T>(T foo) where T : IFoo
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    new Foo().Bar<Foo>(new Foo());
```

Comment: Doesn't this still allow `Foo.Bar()` to be called with *any* class that implements `IFoo`, not just `Foo`?

Comment: Sorry, u need to use Bar<Foo> to fix that. Will edit the answer.